# JSON Schema to validate DateTime without timezone

Tags: jsonschema

JSON Schema date-time format checks for a date-time with a timezone like `2018-11-13T20:20:39+00:00`.

But my date-time does not have a timezone part.

Only date and time like `2018-11-13T20:20:39`.

Is there any way to validate a date-time without a timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "thedate":{
            "type":"string",
            "format":"date-time"
        }   
    }
}
```

will validate this instance:

```
{
    "thedate":"2018-11-13T20:20:39"  
}
```

As pointed out by @gregsdennis, there may be some variation in either support for, or implementation of, the "format" keyword depending on the parser you are using.

As pointed out by @hectorct, even though some validator implementations will validate a date time without a time zone component, it is probably wise to use one anyway; even if this changes the meaning of the data and may cause application code running in a different time zone to deserialise the actual day incorrectly, it is probably a cleaner solution overall.

For example, always add the UTC indicator onto the end of the date time:

```
{
    "thedate":"2018-11-13T20:20:39Z"  
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that not all implementations validate `format`.  It's recommended, but optional.

Comment: Be careful, some validators do not require time zone for date-time, but according to the spec, it is required.